# Expected value of the trace of a matrix

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probabilized space, $A = (A_{i,j})_{1\le i,j\le n}$ such that
$$
\forall i,j, 
\mathbb{P}(A_{i,j}=1) = \mathbb{P}(A_{i,j}=-1)= \frac 1 2
$$
and the random variables are mutually independent. Find $\mathbb{E}(\text{tr}(A^4))$ and $\mathbb{E}(\text{tr}(A^5))$. I tried to compute the sum and study each case (where there is at least two distinct coefficients or not in order to apply the formula with independent random variables on a product) but I'm wondering if there is not another way to do so.

Comment: It is independ$\color{blue}e$nt-two times. Still one word has to be corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is basically what you did. but one you start looking there are not many possibilities. Let me sketch what I did

$$
tr(A^4)=\sum_{ijkl}A_{ij}A_{jk}A_{kl}A_{lm}
$$

Then, there are the following possibilities in the sum

1. $(i,j,k,l)$ are all equal, in which case you just get 1 (with probability 1)
2. $(i,j,k,l)$ are three equal among them and one different. In this case you will have $A_{aa}A_{aa}A_{ab}A_{ba}=A_{ab}A_{ba}$ which has expected value $0$.
3. $(i,j,k,l)$ are two equal and the other two different. Then, as you may check, all $A$'s are different and the expected value is once again 0
4. $(i,j,k,l)$ equal two by two. In this case you get $1$ with probability one if the pairs are $i=k$ and $j=l$ otherwise you get expected value 0
5. Finally if all are different you get expected value 0.

It may be helpful to notice that if you write the labels $(i,j,k,l)$ as the vertices of a square, you get the labels of the $A$'s as the (directed) edges. This makes easy to visualize.

Finally you get just a contribution from cases 1, from which there are $N$ and from cases $4$ from which there are $N(N-1)$. Then
$$
E[tr\,A^4]=N+N(N-1)=N^2.
$$

I believe this is alright but let me know if you find a problem.

Comment: Yes, I did that too and had the same result. Thank you for your advice (if I may, how did you think of the vertices of a square? Is it a common trick?).

Comment: Take a look at the deleted question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2744325 which contains a very rich reference (Wigner matrices generalize your $\pm1$ matrices)

Comment: @JeanMarie "Page not found"...

Comment: I am surprized that you haven't found this page because I have been able just now to reach it. Nevertheless here is the very rich reference cited there using Wigner matrices http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~tkemp/247A.Notes.pdf,

Comment: Yes! the trick is quite usual! I am a physicists so a loop in a Feynman diagram gives rise to a trace. But I am sure they use in many other places

Comment: @David Jaramillo Very interesting remark. I have found this document about relationships between Feynman diagrams and traces : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04182.pdf but it is still not very clear. Could you give another reference ?

Comment: Well, it takes sometimes to understand the Feynman diagram techniques and if you are not interested in physics maybe it is not worth it. At the end it is just a technique to compute a power expansion. If you are really interested, a great book for beginners is Schwartz book on QFT. He has in chapter 3.5 some discussion of classical Feynman diagrams. And I think you want to look at chapter 9 in scalar electrodynamics to see a trace appearing (you need some gauge fields with some indices to be able to trace). There, as I wrote the diagrams, the $A$ you have corresponds to the photon propagator